# Swift if statement in CellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, if-statement, segue

I have a `tableView` where I want to display different Cells depending on what a variable `seguedDisplayMonth` is set to. Is this possible and if so can I get any hint on how to do this? I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Income Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let income = myIncomeArray[indexPath.row]
    if seguedDisplayMonth == "All" {
        var text = "\(income.money) kr"
        cell.textLabel?.text = text
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = income.name
    }
    return cell
}
```

I also thought that maybe I need to reload the data after changing the `seguedDisplayMonth` which gets changed from a different `tableView` and through a `segue`.

Comment: are you presenting programmatically the segue from the other viewController?

Comment: what is `seguedDisplayMonth`?

Comment: `seguedDisplayMonth` is a variable that holds a `String`.

Comment: Not sure with what you mean with that @dirtydanee. I have a prepareForSegue in the other viewController. And then I made a connection in the Storyboard with an identifier.

Comment: your question would be how to associate value to seguedDisplayMonth? You could set it in prepareForSegue in the other viewcontroller.

Comment: The prepareForSwgue is working correctly. seguedDisplayMonth gets the value that I want.

Comment: you would like to display different cells classes or the same cell objects with different value on textLabel and detailTextLabel? And when you say, it does not seem to work, what are you experiencing? Crash?

Comment: Same classes but with different month string values. It doesnt crash but the cells dont change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it finally. I will explain how I did it incase anyone runs into the same problem.

I implemented another `array` `myVisibleIncomeArray`.

In `viewDidLoad()` I called a `function` which does the following:

```
for inc in myIncomeArray {
        if self.monthLabel.text == "All" {
            self.myVisibleIncomeArray.append(inc)
            totalSum += inc.money
            print("Added to myVisible")
        }
    }
```

Then I `reloadData()` and use myVisibleIncomeArray for the other functions.

Not sure if it was the smartest fix, but it's a fix nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Call `mcTableSwag.reloadData()` once `seguedDisplayMonth` is changed. (Likely call it in the function that actually changes `seguedDisplayMonth`.

Alternatively you could reload certian cells with some method like `reloadVisibleCellsAtIndexPath(...)` (Im not sure what it is called exactly, but it should be on the Apple UITableView documentation.

Comment: I change the value in my `viewDidLoad()` but adding `tableView.reloadData()` there, changes nothing.

Comment: make sure `table.reloadData()` is after the change to `seguedDisplayMonth`. If the problem persists add `table.reloadData()` in the `viewDidAppear(...)` function